# Tic Tac Toe: Probabilities of Outcomes with Random Moves *Including* Game-Ending Illegal Moves

Tags: probability, combinatorics, tic-tac-toe

I have a toy problem I've been playing with simulating for fun and learning, and I'd like to have a deeper understanding of the math involved. So, I'm curious:

Given a randomly-played game between two players who *don't even know the rules*, how would I calculate the odds of the four possible outcomes: **x wins, o wins, draw, invalid game**

To elaborate, on each turn, each player is playing randomly without even knowing what the legal moves are. So the 'x' player might try to play an 'o' (resulting in an invalid game), or might try to play an 'x' in a square that already contains an 'x', etc.

In my simulations, I see a majority of invalid games (as one would expect), and some games where 'x' or 'o' wins, but I almost never see drawn games. Intuitively this makes sense because a draw requires all 9 squares to be filled in, which means the odds of an illegal move by that point are at their highest. However, I'm seeing so few draws I wonder whether there's a bug in my simulation code. But I can't verify that without a deeper understanding of the mathematics!

But how would I calculate the true odds involved in each outcome?

Thanks!

Comment: So if a player plays an X where there is already an X, that makes the game invalid as well, no?

Comment: Yes that's correct!

Comment: Then it's pretty easy. As long as the game is valid, its odds are the same as the normal tic-tac-toe game, which I can leave to you to find out. The probability of it being valid is $\frac{9!}{9^9}$.

Comment: Assuming the first move is always good (and establishes whether or not player 1 is x or o) then the probability that we make 9 moves with all correct symbols, and never repeating a location, is $$\underbrace{[(1/2)(8/9)]}_{\mbox{move 2}} [(1/2)(7/9)] [(1/2)(6/9)] [(1/2)(5/9)] [(1/2)(4/9)] [(1/2)(3/9)] [(1/2)(2/9)] \underbrace{[(1/2)(1/9)]}_{\mbox{move 9}} \approx 3.65 \times 10^{-6}$$ where on move 2 we have $(1/2)(8/9)$ chance of choosing the correct symbol and in a non-taken location, and so on.  This is an upper bound on the draw probability as the game may end in a win before this happens.

Comment: Fascinating. So in a million runs we should only expect ~3 drawn games. And if we don't assume the first move is always good, then we just add [(1/2)(9/9)] to our sequence, giving us ~1.5 expected draws in a million runs, yes?

Comment: Yes. If the first player always has to be x, then you multiply $[(1/2)(9/9)]$ and the above bound becomes $1.82 \times 10^{-6}$. I don't have much intuition on how much lower the true value is due to the case of a win before a draw, but your guess of about $1.5$ per million seems reasonable.  What is your simulated number?

Comment: 0-2 per million runs, so definitely in the neighborhood of what the math suggests. Though I haven't run enough millions for a specific %

Comment: If we restrict only to when the players make legal moves, but we do not stop when a player wins, the probability of achieving a drawn game should be the same as the probability of achieving a drawn game when we stop earlier. So, out of the 126 possible end game positions, there are 90 valid end games (with at most one winner). There are 16 drawn endgames, 12 where the second player has won, and 62 where the first player has won. So, I believe if you multiply the probability of reaching the 9th turn by $$\dfrac{16}{90}$$ it should give you the probability of a draw. Or maybe $$\dfrac{16}{126}$$

Comment: I thought more about it. It is definitely $\dfrac{16}{126}$.